# Google Analytics - Identifying Bots

Tags: google-analytics, spam

I've noticed over the last few days a massive increase in visitors,

The thing is that it seems like a bot:

- Mozilla compatible user agent
- average 0 minutes
- 100% bounces

Is there a way to find out who/where this bot is from?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete description for your question:

[Bot traffic in Google Analytics](http://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/analytics/tag/bot-traffic-in-google-analytics)

Comment: Please paraphrase the content of links provided in your answers so that if the link is no longer available, the answer will still be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, It's actually a very similar article I went through before posting. But please notice that I'm trying to investigate who is this bot from, I already figured out it was a bot! thanks